# How to write this simple Monad that can chang any item of a record?

Tags: haskell

I have these data types,which means a box of candy:

```
data Candy=Candy {name::String,price::Int}

data Box=Box Candy

let toffee=Candy {name="toffee",price=1}

let box=Box {candy=toffee}
```

I want make the Box as instance of Monad,that can do this:

```
box>>=x->return x {name="Toffee",price=2}
```

or

```
box>>=x->return x {name="Toffee"}
```

or

```
box>>=x->return x {price=2}
```

or

```
box>>=x->
  if (name x=="toffee") return x {name="Toffee",price=2}
  else return x {name="other"}
```

I am new to haskell,I try to write this but fail:

```
instance Monad Box where
 return x=Box x
 Box x>>=f=f x
```

so how to write this monad?Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to make `Box` as instance of `Monad`? Actually, it cannot, because every instance of `Monad` must have a polymorphic type parameter, like `data Box a = Box a`. You cannot specify it only for `Candy` type.

Comment: `Box` *cannot* be a monad because it has no type parameter.

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do, I think you don't need monads at all.

Comment: I we're supposed to make sense of what you're trying to achieve here, please add some more realistic example, make sure it uses proper, correct Haskell syntax, and show what you'd want the result to be.

Comment: I wonder if you are thinking of the State monad, with Box as the state parameter. See https://wiki.haskell.org/State_Monad and http://brandon.si/code/the-state-monad-a-tutorial-for-the-confused/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have noted, none of your examples require a Monad.  All are valid if you leave out the `>>=` and `return`.  For example:

```
expensiveToffee (Box box) = Box (box {name="Toffee",price=2})

isToffee (Box box) = 
  if (name box=="toffee") 
  then Box (box {name="Toffee",price=2})
  else Box (box {name="other"})
```

As an aside, since several of these don't actually use any fields of the `Box`, you can construct a `Candy` directly instead of using the record-update syntax.

```
expensiveToffee2 (Box _box) = Box (Candy {name="Toffee",price=2})
```

or even skip the input to this function, since it is ignored:

```
expensiveToffee3 = Box (Candy {name="Toffee",price=2})
```

Comment: The thing inside a `Box` is a `Candy`, so it is confusing to bind it to a variable named `box`